# Scroll view content size should adjust according to orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c

My code is  `[scrllView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, 1000)];` so that its width appear on whole screen. But when I am changing the orientation to landscape, its width is not adjusting. I think it is not working because i am doing it in `viewDidLoad` method, .So it will calulate the width only once. But what will be the possible solution of this. **`scrLlView` Should adjust width**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;
{
 //change sub view of scrollview accordingly to orientation
 if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
     yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
     yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,460);//change accordingly
 else
     yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,480,300);
     yourScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(480,500); //change accordingly

 return YES;
}

[yourScrollView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

additional [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13430379/uiscrollview-content-size-when-orientation-changes)